# Структура: Выражение должно быть допустимым для изменения левосторонним значением

Tags: c++, указатели, структуры

Хочу реализовать заполнение структуры случайным образом (проблема в реализации функции random_filling). Идея в том чтобы генерировать рандомное число и и по этому числу будут браться элементы с данным индексом с массивов elements, nums, temperatures и viscosities. Но проблема в том что в функцию передается указатель, а в работе с ними я ещё не силен. Буду признателен за помощь.
Ссылка на код: http://cpp.sh/6nnat

Comment: Код здесь помещают в вопрос.

Comment: посмотрел в код. Там плюсы или все таки си?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартная ошибка начинающего - пытаться присваивать что-то массиву с помощью оператора `=`.

Я не пытаюсь разобраться, правильный ли ваш код в смысле семантики (уверен, что нет - например, у вас есть указатель `char*tmp`, и вы пытаетесь копировать `&tmp` - т.е. просто значение этого адреса, не говоря уж о том, что переменная неинициализирована, и присвоение `temp[h]` в паре строк ниже - это запись в непонятное место в памяти, которое скорее всего обвалит программу. Но это уже тема для других вопросов...

Если у вас есть массив? что-то вроде

```
char s[100];
```

и вы хотите поместить в него какую-то строку, скажем, *на которую указывает* указатель `t`

```
char * t;
```

или которая находится в другом массиве

```
char t[100];
```

то для этого используется [функция копирования строки](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy)

```
strcpy(s,t);
```

или ее более безопасная версия `strcpy_s` или `dtrncpy`.

Ваша запись - типа `s = t;` - означает, что вы просто хотите заменить значение указателя. Но поскольку `s` - это статически выделенный массив, эта переменная меняться не может; ей ничего присваивать нельзя.

Еще раз - ваша программа после исправления, вероятно, будет компилироваться, но вот правильно работать будет вряд ли...